# java: Move elements in a char[][] array by one space either north, south, east, west, etc.

Tags: java, arrays, methods, char

I had an assignment wherein I need to move elements of a 10x10 char array by one position either north, south, east, west, or NE, NW, etc.

I wrote a method to fill the array w/ B for bear and F for fish, or a blank space for null.

I then wrote a method to move the elements, but i keep getting the error 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"

I have no clue what's wrong since im not getting any errors before compiling.

Here is my code:

```
package project1final;
public class Project1Final {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char [][] river = new char[10][10]; //2D array to simulate a river 
        fill_river(river); //fill array river 
        printArray(river); //print array river  
        move_elements(river); 
        System.out.println(); 
        printArray(river); 
    }

    //method to fill river matrix
    public static char[][] fill_river(char[][] river) {
        char bear = 'B'; //bear 
        char fish = 'F'; //fish 
        for (int i = 0; i < river.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < river[0].length; j++) {
                int random = (int)(Math.random() * 3 + 1); //generate random number 
                if (random == 1) {
                    river[i][j] = bear; 
                } //random == 1 = bear 
                else if (random == 2) {
                    river[i][j] = fish; 
                } //else if random == 2 = fish 
                else {
                    river[i][j] = ' '; 
                } //else = null
            } //for j loop
        } //for i loop    
        return river; //return filled matrix river 
    }

    //print array method 
    public static void printArray(char river[][]) {
        int count = 0; //count variable 
        for (int i = 0; i < river.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < river[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(river[i][j] + " "); //print 
                count++; //increment the count 
                if (count == river.length) {
                    System.out.println(); //print new line 
                    count = 0; //count starts over
                } //print a new line 
            } //for j loop
       } //for i loop
    }

    //method to move river elements 
    public static char[][] move_elements(char[][] river) {
        int move = (int)(Math.random() * 4 + 1); //random number 1-4
        for (int i = 0; i < river.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < river[0].length; j++) {  
                while (river[i][j] > river[i-1][j-1] && river[i][j] < river[i+1][j+1]) {
                    if (move == 1) {
                        river[i][j] = river[i+1][j]; //moves south 
                    }
                    else if (move == 2) {
                        river[i][j] = river[i-1][j]; //moves north  
                    }
                    else if (move == 3) {
                        river[i][j] = river[i][j+1]; //moves east  
                    }
                    else if (move == 4) {
                        river[i][j] = river[i][j-1]; //moves west  
                    }
                }
            } //for loop j
        } //for loop i
        return river; 
    }
}
```

Again, my question is: how do I move the elements of my array (B, F and " ") by one space using a method.

Comment: "I have no clue what's wrong since im not getting any errors before compiling.",   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is a runtime exception

Comment: On your "move_elements" method, your first "while" iteration sets "i=-1" and "j=-1" , since both "i" and "j" are zero. That's why you're getting the AIOOBE. You have to take into account if you're on the "edges" of your river.

Comment: Josh if any answer solved your question please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly accessing out of bounds memory:

`while (river[i][j] > river[i-1][j-1] && river[i][j] < river[i+1][j+1])`

And in many other `if` statements that are all around your code.
 You can see how `river[i+1][j+1]` will attempt to access out of bounds memory when you reach the end of your `river` array.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you move your elements also if they are at the "*border*" of the river.

You need to check if it is possible to do that or not, for example:

```
if (move == 1 && i + 1 < river.length) {
    river[i][j] = river[i+1][j]; //moves south ONLY if you can go south 
}
```

What happens if you try to go south but it is not possible?
There are many possible alternatives:

- You stop there (don't move if not possible)
- You invert the movement (so instead going south, go north)
- You pass from bottom to top of array (so from bottom go to the top)

Depending on your choice you can have different codes. The example shown before is for the first possibility.

Comment: The OP is doing this sort of thing in *so many* other places.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is homework, it's not a decent move to post your entire project and expect Stackoverflow to figure this out.

What I would is us the `paper+pencil` debug algorithm:

1. Take a piece of paper
2. Draw your array. (It's 10x10, not that hard to draw.)
3. Create a print method for your array and draw the items in your array according to your print
4. Attempt to use `move_elements` on your piece of paper.

This is a far more valuable answer than just tell you why your code is buggy. Welcome to the world of debugging :)

Anyway, the problem is that you are not handling the `worst cases` of your code.

Say you have a `FISH/BEAR` at the northest/southest/eastest/westest possible position. If the dice rolls a 2, then your implementation will move it to `RIVER[-1][...]`. Is this a valid index for your array??? That's why you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Add more `flow control statements(if's)` to handle these situations.

You would have been able to figure this out more easily if you used the `paper+pencil` method that was stated above.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a position that does not exist in your array.
Here is a simple example of something simple and similar to what you want, you just need to get the idea from here and adapt your code:

```
public class MoveArray{

    static void printArray(String [][] myArray) {
        for (String[] strings : myArray) {
            for (String string : strings) {
                System.out.print(string + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static String[][] moveRight(String [][] myArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = myArray.length-1; j > 0 ; j--) {
                myArray[i][j] = myArray[i][j-1];
                if (j == 1) myArray[i][j-1] = "0";
            }
        }
        return myArray;
    }

    static String[][] moveLeft(String [][] myArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length-1; j++) {
                myArray[i][j] = myArray[i][j+1];
                if (j == myArray.length-2) myArray[i][j+1] = "0";
            }
        }
        return myArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [][] s = {{"1","1","1"},{"1","1","1"},{"1","1","1"}};
        printArray(s);

        System.out.println("\nMove right");
        printArray(moveRight(s));

        System.out.println("\nMove left");
        printArray(moveLeft(s));
    }
}
```