# Bidimensional array movement with cardinal directions

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have this problem in my mind. How could I search in a infinite bidimensional array [,] with North South West East starting somewhere and couting +1 in every new position never coming back to a previous position? For example:

Input: North, Output: 2 (1 + 1)
Input: North, West, South, South, Output: 4 (1 + 1 + 1 + 1)
Input: North, South, North Output: Error (been at this position before)

This is a similar post ([java: Move elements in a char[][] array by one space either north, south, east, west, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700087/java-move-elements-in-a-char-array-by-one-space-either-north-south-east)), at least for the loop part, that I already know.

My problem is more how to save previous position and never go there again.
Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Can't you just store them in a list? If you show some code, that would really help. As [edit] please

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the visited positions and check before entering a new one whether it is already visited or not. Below given is a rough idea of how you may proceed with the main alogrithm for that.

```
var directions = new List<Direction(); // get these from somewhere
int x = start_x, y = start_y;
var error = false;

foreach (var direction in directions)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case Direction.North:
            if (array[x, y + 1])
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
            ++y;
            break;
        case Direction.South:
            if (array[x, y - 1])
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
            --y;
            break;
        case Direction.East:
            if (array[x + 1, y])
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
            ++x;
            break;
        case Direction.West:
            if (array[x - 1, y])
            {
                error = true;
                break;
            }
            --x;
            break;
    }

    if (!error)
    {
        array[x,y] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```